# Drawing box using timestamp

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

As title says im trying to plot a box using 2 timestamps (start and stop).
Considering the High and Low inside this range.

Here an image:
[image: Example of the result]

Well i tried to do something but im stuck with the dates. For now i use an int box to go back to the date, but its a bit complicated when change timeframe.

Here's the code:

```
//@version=5
indicator('Test Box', overlay=true)

lenght = input.int(200,    title='Lenght')
show   = input.bool(true,  title='Show Box')

lowPrice  = ta.lowest(low,   lenght)
highPrice = ta.highest(high, lenght)

if barstate.ishistory
  
   if show
      _Bot   = line.new(bar_index[lenght], lowPrice,  bar_index,         lowPrice)
      _Top   = line.new(bar_index[lenght], highPrice, bar_index,         highPrice)
      _Left  = line.new(bar_index[lenght], highPrice, bar_index[lenght], lowPrice)
      _Right = line.new(bar_index,         highPrice, bar_index,         lowPrice)

      line.delete(_Bot[1])
      line.delete(_Top[1])
      line.delete(_Left[1])
      line.delete(_Right[1])
```

Any suggestion to get the result displayed in image but using timestamps form start and end date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`box.new()` has an argument called `xloc`. You can set it to `xloc.bar_time` and then use your timestamps for the `left` and `right`.

Below example shows you how to do that:

```
start = timestamp(2023, 01, 01, 00, 00)
end = timestamp(2023, 01, 15, 00, 00)

draw_box = (time[1] < end) and (time >= end)    // Only draw the box when the end date is reached

if (draw_box)
    box.new(start, high, end, low, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
```

You then just need to find the top and bottom range.

Comment: Thanks Vitruvius for your help. So i've one another question related. How can i get now top and bottom range? cause if i use `box.new()` using the dates,  i cant use `lenght` variable as before. i should know how many N go back, should i subtracts dates?

Comment: You don't need to go back. Use the `start` and `end` variables and update your range only when `(time >= start) and (time <= end)`.

Comment: Thank again Vitruvius, was really helpfull!